# Razor adding extra newline character and white spaces to hyperlinks

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, hyperlink

I'm writing a web application that parses a text file and replaces line numbers with hyperlinks so that the user can easily navigate to a specific line number of the text file they inputted.

I'm printing a list of objects stored in the Viewbag within a .cshtml View. When I print everything as normal text, everything looks fine. For example:

```
--------
Summary
--------
Version             23.00.00.00
Error 007           2   at lines    (09/02/2014-06:13:32.607, 5662);
Timeouts            0
Reboots             1   at lines    (09/02/2014-06:12:59.900, 2)
```

But when I print the line numbers as hyperlinks, this happens:

```
--------
Summary
--------
Version             23.00.00.00
Error 007           2   at lines    (09/02/2014-06:13:32.607,                [5662]
);
Timeouts            0
Reboots             1   at lines    (09/02/2014-06:12:59.900,                [2]
)
```

My parser works just fine when the hyperlinks are printed as normal strings, so it looks like razor is adding extra white space before each hyperlink and an extra newline character after each hyperlink. Here is the code within the View:

```
<pre>     
        @for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.links.Count; i++)
        { 
            if (ViewBag.links[i].isHyperLink == true)
            {
                <a href="@ViewBag.links[i].url">@ViewBag.links[i].text</a> //hyperlink printed
            }  
            if (ViewBag.links[i].isHyperLink == false)
            {
                @ViewBag.links[i].text; //normal text printed
            }
        }
</pre>
```

I'm quite the asp.net/razor noob so any help is very much appreciated. Thanks for your time.

P.S. I've put the text that is supposed to be hyperlinked within brackets. The hyperlink functionality didn't carry over well to stackoverflow.

edit: Here is the source as requested

```
--------
Summary
--------
Version             23.00.00.00
Error 007           2   at lines    (09/02/2014-06:13:32.607,                <a href="C:\Users\GBALL\project\project_folder\website\Home\UploadFiles~/App_Data/Uploads/bloop.txt">5662</a>
); 
Timeouts                0
Reboots             1   at lines    (09/                <a href="C:\Users\GBALL\project\project_folder\website\Home\UploadFiles~/App_Data/Uploads/bloop.txt">2</a>
/2014-06:12:59.900, 2)
```

Comment: Would you be able to post the generated HTML so that we can see what it looks like once parsed and rendered?

Comment: The first two blocks I posted are the generated html. The only difference being that the second block has bracketed numbers rather than the actual hyperlinks. Other than that, they are identical to the generated html.

Comment: ok so in the generated html, other than the id value is there any other text or characters being added to the hyperlink text?

Comment: No, the first two blocks you posted are the representation of the HTML in the browser. View source and post the actual generate source.

Comment: No. That was the first thing I checked. The values within ViewBag.links[i].text are simply "5662" and "2" respectively. There are no extra characters being added.

Comment: This is most likely a CSS issue. But, nobody will be able to help you unless you post the generated HTML code.

Comment: As requested, I've posted the generated html.

Comment: You are wrapping the link in a `<pre>`, which means all white spaces and newline signs will be preserved, including the tab/space before the link and newline after the link. Any reason for using `<pre>` instead of regular `<div>` or `<span>`?

Comment: That's still not the generated html code you have posted here. Go to the source view in your browser, copy the source, and paste it here. You have obviously just manually added the `<a>` tags here.

Comment: I used <pre> because otherwise the text prints out in a gigantic block without any newline or tab characters. For some reason neither <div> or <span> registers that tabs or newlines are there. I want newline and tabs to be preserved, but i don't want extra ones being added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser always ignores whitespace when rendering HTML. That's why the `<pre>` element exists. It's sole function is to tell the browser to actually take the whitespace into account when rendering. However, it's an either or proposition: either you see the whitespace, all the whitespace, or you don't.  That means that if you're going to use a preformatted block, then you need to pay attention to the whitespace in your Razor code. You can do something like:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.links.Count; i++)
{ 
    if (ViewBag.links[i].isHyperLink == true)
    {<a href="@ViewBag.links[i].url">@ViewBag.links[i].text</a>}  
    else
    {@ViewBag.links[i].text}
}
```

Notice how the code brackets have been collapsed around the text so that no whitespace exists. Or, preferably, since the above is quite ugly use something like a ternary:

```
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.links[i].isHyperLink == true
    ? string.Format("<a href='{0}'>{1}</a>", ViewBag.links[i].url, ViewBag.links[i].text)
    : ViewBag.links[i].text)
```

Comment: This did it! Thanks so much. Simply putting {<a href="@ViewBag.links[i].url">@ViewBag.links[i].text</a>} was all I needed to do.